# Why does this request return an empty string?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have the following function which makes a get request to a url.

```
def fetch_data(session = None):
    s = session or requests.Session()
    url = 'http://www.moldelectrica.md/utils/load4.php'
    response = s.get(url)
    print response.status_code
    data = response.text
    return data
```

I expect to get a string back in the form.

169,26,0,19,36,151,9,647,26,15,0,0,0,0,0,150,7,27,-11,-27,-101,-19,-32,-78,-58,0,962,866,96,0,50.02

But instead I get an empty unicode string.  The status code returned is 200.

I've looked at the request headers but nothing in them suggests that any headers will require being set manually.  Cookies are used but I think the session object should handle that.

Comment: The page is empty when I access the URL with a browser. Is there some reason why you expect it to contain data?

Comment: Is this your site...the URL returned no content for me...if it is...check URE PHP code

Comment: Not my site, this url is called by another page on the site and provides data for a display.  I'm using Firefox and see a string like 73,20,0,19,36,154,9,523,18,8,0,0,0,0,0,176,8,27,-6,27,-50,-17,-27,-69,-51,0,884,746,138,0,50.00

Comment: Though when I try accessing that url with Chrome I get an empty page, interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  As I said this url provides data for a display so it wouldn't normally be visited directly.  Usually it would be requested by the display page and that page would provide a cookie.

So the solution is to make a request to the display url then reuse the session and make another request to the data url.